# Trying To Summon Another PHP Page Using POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I am tring to summon one PHP page (`ModifyUsers.php`) from another (`RumpUserAdministration.php`).  I am trying to summon it as a separate page, rather than as a subsection of the User Administration page, and to pass value `userID` using POST from `RumpUserAdministration.php` to `ModifyUsers.php`.

I have added `alert` statements which show that `userID` is stored within `hidden-id-field` immediately prior to the summoning of the Modify Users page, and thus available for POSTing, but that it is not transported to the Modify Users page.

I have also `alert` added statements that indicate which Server Request Method is in use at those points in the execution of the page. Other buttons present on my page will similarly need to summon other pages.

My question is this: how do I summon my Modify Users page using POST so that I may transfer my value using POST?

I am capable of using both GET and SESSION variables, but this particular scenario is focussed on POST - GET and SESSION variables are not to be used.

I have consulted my fellow students and all of my lecturers in regards this problem as well as having trawled through over 20 different sites and multiple searches in my search for a solution.  None of the "solutions" proposed proved to be at all effective - the people are now just as flummoxed as I and the web-pages used methods that were only suitable for updating the source page rather summoning a new one or just plain wrong.

The following are the files that I have been using for this problem.

RumpUserAdministration.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        >

        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <link href = "CSS/RumpIntranetProject.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css"
        >
    </head>

    <body>
<?php
        echo "<script>alert( \"" . $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] . "\" )</script>";
?>
        <form id     = "entire-page"
              action = "RumpUserAdministration.php"
              method = "post"
        >
            <div id = "user-name-list-section">
                <div id = "user-name-list">
                    <div id      = "ID15"
                         class   = "list-item row"
                         name    = "ID15"
                         onclick = "userNameListItemClicked( '15' )"
                    >
                        SAMPLE USER 001
                    </div>

                    <div id      = "ID16"
                         class   = "list-item row"
                         name    = "ID16"
                         onclick = "userNameListItemClicked( '16' )"
                    >
                        SAMPLE USER 002
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input id      = "user-administration-button-delete"
                   name    = "delete-submit"
                   onclick = "loadDeleteUsers()"
                   type    = "submit"
                   value   = "Delete"
            >

            <input id      = "user-administration-button-modify"
                   name    = "modify-submit"
                   onclick = "loadModifyUsers()"
                   type    = "submit"
                   value   = "Modify"
            >

            <input id    = 'hidden-id-field'
                   name  = 'userID'
                   type  = 'hidden'
                   value = ''
            >
        </form>

        <?php
            if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" )
            {
                if ( isset( $_POST[ 'modify-submit' ] ) )
                {
                    echo "<script>document.getElementById( 'hidden-id-field' ).value = \"" . $_POST[ 'userID' ] . "\"</script>";
                    echo "<script>alert( \"hidden-id-field (userID) : \" + document.getElementById( 'hidden-id-field' ).value )</script>";
                    echo "<script>alert( \"" . $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] . "\" )</script>";
                    echo '<script>window.location = "ModifyUsers.php"</script>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert( 'Unexpected Administration POST encountered.' )</script>";
                }
            }
        ?>

        <script>
            var existingSelection = null;

            function loadModifyUsers()
            {
                document.getElementById( 'hidden-id-field' ).value = existingSelection;
                alert( "Presubmit" );
                document.getElementById( 'entire-page' ).submit;
            }

            function userNameListItemClicked( userID )
            {
                existingSelection = 'ID' + userID;

                document.getElementById( "user-administration-button-modify" ).style.cursor = "pointer";
                document.getElementById( "user-administration-button-modify" ).disabled = false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ModifyUsers.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        >

        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <link href = "CSS/RumpIntranetProject.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css"
        >
    </head>

    <body>
<?php
        echo "<script>alert( 'In further' )</script>";
        echo "<script>alert( \"hidden-id-field (userID) : \" + document.getElementById( 'hidden-id-field' ).value )</script>";
        echo "<script>alert( \"userID : \" + \"" . $_POST[ 'userID' ] . "\" )</script>";
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

RumpIntranetProject.css

```
html,
*
{
    border      : 0;
    box-sizing  : border-box;
    margin      : 0;
    padding     : 0;
}

.list-item
{
    display : block;
}

.list-item:hover
{
    background-color : #00ffff;
}

.row:after
{
    clear   : both;
    content : "";
    display : block;
}

#user-name-list
{
    border       : 1px;
    border-color : black;
    border-style : solid;
    overflow-y   : scroll;
    width        : 300px;
}
```

I am not sure if this problem is due to a missed `include`, typo, wrong command or whichever, I can not say where the fault lies.  As such in the interests of completeness I must include the full contents of each minimalised file. I'm working on my definition of "minimal". :)

Comment: Two pieces of advice: (1) simplify this wall of code and produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and (2) save yourself a lot of pain by never using spaces in your PHP file names.

Comment: Spaces removed - no effect.  More to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ed Cottrell.  I have been looking for this document.

Comment: I have edited the document to hopefully make it more manageable.  Feel free to offer any suggestions for improvement or to ask any questions you may have.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using JavaScript to change the page:

```
echo '<script>window.location = "ModifyUsers.php"</script>';
```

What you are doing here *is* loading `ModifyUsers.php`, but [as this is a GET] nothing can be passed via POST.

What you need to do instead is change the `action` of the form to go to `ModifyUsers.php`: that way your POST data gets passed to the correct page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This is fine if Modify Users is the only page being summoned from a one button form.  But my full User Administation page presents other options to the user, such as also allowing them to summon a Delete Users page.  How do I summon the Modify Users page only when they click on the Modify button (and pass the value using POST)?  Please Note : I have updated my Question to reflect this aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is one answer that I just developed.  If there are other ways of answering the question, then please post them.

I have placed each Submit button within its own form, including a hidden field in each form.

Each of these buttons successfully summons its form and not something else.

The following is the modified version of RumpUserAdministration.php that I used (ModifyUsers.php and RumpIntranetProject.css are unchanged from the question).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        >

        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <link href = "CSS/RumpIntranetProject.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css"
        >
    </head>

    <body>
<?php
        echo "<script>alert( \"" . $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] . "\" )</script>";
?>
        <div id = "user-name-list-section">
            <div id = "user-name-list">
                <div id      = "ID15"
                     class   = "list-item row"
                     name    = "ID15"
                     onclick = "userNameListItemClicked( '15' )"
                >
                    SAMPLE USER 001
                </div>

                <div id      = "ID16"
                     class   = "list-item row"
                     name    = "ID16"
                     onclick = "userNameListItemClicked( '16' )"
                >
                    SAMPLE USER 002
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form id     = "form-delete"
              action = "Index.php"
              method = "post"
        >
            <input id    = 'hidden-id-field-delete'
                   name  = 'userID'
                   type  = 'hidden'
                   value = ''
            >
            <input id      = "user-administration-button-delete"
                   name    = "delete-submit"
                   onclick = "loadDeleteUsers()"
                   type    = "submit"
                   value   = "Delete"
            >
        </form>

        <form id     = "form-modify"
              action = "ModifyUsers.php"
              method = "post"
        >
            <input id    = 'hidden-id-field-modify'
                   name  = 'userID'
                   type  = 'hidden'
                   value = ''
            >

            <input id      = "user-administration-button-modify"
                   name    = "modify-submit"
                   onclick = "loadModifyUsers()"
                   type    = "submit"
                   value   = "Modify"
            >
        </form>

        <script>
            var existingSelection = null;

            function loadDeleteUsers()
            {
                document.getElementById( 'hidden-id-field-delete' ).value = existingSelection;
            }

            function loadModifyUsers()
            {
                document.getElementById( 'hidden-id-field-modify' ).value = existingSelection;
            }

            function userNameListItemClicked( userID )
            {
                existingSelection = 'ID' + userID;

                document.getElementById( "user-administration-button-modify" ).style.cursor = "pointer";
                document.getElementById( "user-administration-button-modify" ).disabled = false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```